how to turn off "...migrated from Rhino to V8 runtime" banner in Google Apps Script Editor?
When I go into Script Editor (e.g. from a Google Sheet or Google Doc), I get a banner at the top of the window that says "This script has been migrated from Rhino to V8 runtime."
There are buttons to "Learn more" and "Dismiss".

How do I turn off this banner permanently for all scripts? It's really annoying to have to Dismiss it every. single. time.

Have you tried migrating the scripts using these procedures V8 migration procedure ?

Use a popup blocker like ublock origin?

@TheMaster An excellent example of Poe's law

@Tedinoz Not sure I understand, but I wasn't being sarcastic, but seriously recommending ublock origin to remove that popup.

Does this answer your question? Google Apps Script -- Hide "Running Script" notification . I think there’s a similarity to your problem.

Edward, dismiss it for a few days and finally the system will "understand" that you are already aware of the situation.

Thanks. I'll been dismissing it for...over a year? I've dismissed probably several hundred, maybe over 1000 times.
And to be clear, it's in the Script Editor and it shows up when you first open Script Editor from within a Google Sheet/Doc. It's not related to the "Running Script" notifications. It shows up before I do anything at all.
I'll have to play around with blockers to see if that helps.

There is no built-in way to dismiss the banner on all the Apps Script projects migrated to V8 at once. Please submit your feedback directly to Google using the Issue Tracker. Ref. How to get Help.
As was mentioned in the comments, one workaround is to use user-created scripts, like userscript, user styles, and snippets, to hide the banner. Using "general purpose" web browser extensions like Tamper Monkey or uBlock Origin, among others, might help to handle the script, but a few are specific for the Google Apps Script web IDE, like Black Apps Script. I suggest you search the Chrome Extensions Marketplace to look at the details of the available extensions.
If you don't like extensions, consider using Chrome Web DevTools snippets.

Open DevTools, i.e., press F12.
Open Sources > Snippets

For a detailed explanation on using Snippets see Run snippets of JavaScript
